# Full faith and credit to D.C

Tags: us-constitution, full-faith-and-credit

In the case of Loving v. State of Virginia, the Supreme Court struck down state laws forbidding interracial marriage (I think there may have been 22 states with such laws).  The couple had married in the District of Columbia.

Would the state have refrained from prosecuting them if they had married in a state whose laws allowed interracial marriage, because of the full-faith-and-credit clause in the Constitution?  Generally, what degree of "faith and credit" does D.C. get?  And did that bear upon the Loving case?

Comment: *Loving v. Virginia* will not help you examine the question of full faith and credit for the District's acts.  It hinges on the Equal Protection and Due Process clauses of the 14th amendment.  The decision does not contain the words *full, faith,* or *credit.*  Rather than saying that Virginia must recognize their marriage concluded in DC, the court invalidated the Virginia statute under which they were convicted, and reversed their convictions.  See https://scholar.google.com/scholar_case?case=5103666188878568597#p3.

Comment: @phoog : You seem to misunderstand the question.  I was asking whether the full-faith-and-credit clause WOULD have prevented the prosecution from going ahead if the wedding had been in a state rather than in DC.  And whether that might be why they chose DC, so they could make a test case of it. And thus whether DC gets less "faith and credit" than states do.

Comment: I was specifically addressing "And did that bear upon the Loving case?" That's not in the conditional mood. This is why I posted a comment instead of an answer, since that seems ancillary to your main question. I realize now that it may of course have come up during arguments, or in a lower court. But what you'd really want is a decision that relies on FF&C for an act of the District of Columbia.

Comment: @phoog : I had in mind that it would "bear upon" the case because a court might hold that DC should not get the same faith and credit that a state would get and therefore they could not throw the case out based on the full-faith-and-credit clause.  Thus it might "bear upon the case" precisely by _not_ getting mentioned in the court's written decision.

Comment: I'm unclear why you think full faith and credit is even relevant here. The issue wasn't "Virginia is denying recognition to the marriage." It was "Virginia makes it a crime for Virginians of different races to get married in another state and return to Virginia as a married couple." Whether or not Virginia would recognize them as married was irrelevant, because the case had nothing to do with Virginia not recognizing a marriage.

Comment: @cpast : The situation fails to demonstrate that Virginia viewed it as a crime for them to go to another STATE and get married, since they did not go to another STATE and get married.  Virginia legislators may well have viewed that as a crime, but the state may have been barred from treating it that way because of the full-faith-and-credit clause. But maybe they were not barred from treating it that way when it was DC rather than another state.

Comment: @MichaelHardy The law: "If any white person and colored person shall go out of this State, for the purpose of being married, and with the intention of returning, and be married out of it, and afterwards return to and reside in it, cohabiting as man and wife, they shall be punished as provided in § 20-59, and the marriage shall be governed by the same law as if it had been solemnized in this State."

Comment: Also, your assumption that full faith and credit applies to marriages in the first place is not entirely uncontroversial. There are strong arguments that FF&C doesn't stop states from ignoring marriages from another state contrary to their own laws. FF&C does not say "anything another state does, you must respect;" it's really only that strong for court *judgments*. When dealing with other state actions, there's often a public policy exception.

Comment: @cpast : I wasn't assuming; I was asking.  And it sounds as if you don't know the answer because you haven't said that in 1967 the state of Virginia did or did not recognize interracial marriages from other states.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/41137/discussion-between-cpast-and-michael-hardy).

Answer (score 1):

In the Wikipedia article [Full Faith and Credit Clause](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Full_Faith_and_Credit_Clause) in specific regard to marriage, it is said that:

> Until the Supreme Court struck down all laws banning interracial marriage in 1967, a number of states banned interracial marriage and did not recognize marriage certificates issued in other states for interracial couples. The full faith and credit clause was never used to force a state to recognize a marriage it did not wish to recognize.[16] However, the existence of a common-law marriage in a sister state (still available in nine states and the District of Columbia) has been recognized in divorce or dissolution of marriage cases.

This seems to imply that DC was treated as if it was a state, but FF&C was not used to restrict Virginia and other states with similar laws.

In regard to the public policy limitations of the FF&C clause, the same article, quoting *Pacific Employers Insurance v. Industrial Accident* says:

> [T]here are some limitations upon the extent to which a state may be required by the full faith and credit clause to enforce even the judgment of another state in contravention of its own statutes or policy. See *Wisconsin v. Pelican Insurance Co*., 127 U.S. 265; *Huntington v. Attrill*, 146 U.S. 657; *Finney v. Guy*, 189 U.S. 335; see also *Clarke v. Clarke*, 178 U.S. 186; *Olmsted v. Olmsted*, 216 U.S. 386; *Hood v. McGehee*, 237 U.S. 611; cf. *Gasquet v. Fenner*, 247 U.S. 16. And in the case of statutes...the full faith and credit clause does not require one state to substitute for its own statute, applicable to persons and events within it, the conflicting statute of another state, even though that statute is of controlling force in the courts of the state of its enactment with respect to the same persons and events

I have not been able to find a reported case where the FF&C clause was used to give effect to a DC judgment or law, but I did find [*Rollins v. Rollins* 602 A.2d 1121 (1992)](https://law.justia.com/cases/district-of-columbia/court-of-appeals/1992/91-41-4.html) where DC was required to extend FF&C to a Maryland judgment, although in this case the decision was that the judgment was not final and so did not apply.

Based on all this, I do not think the *Loving* case would have been substantially different had the marring occurred in another state, say New York, that permitted such marriages at the time. The Virginia statute at issue in the case certainly seemed aimed at such situations.